# APScheduler How to set different time in weekday?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am new to Python.
My question is how to set up a scheduler working on weekday. Start at Monday 8am and end at Friday 5pm?

Within this period has multiple interval jobs.

Job1 for every hour and job2 for every 4 hour. Can I use different scheduler? like

```
    def job1():
       print('job 1 hour')

    def job2():
       print('job 4 hour') 

    if __name__=='__main__':
       job1()
       job2()

       sched1 = BackgroundScheduler()
       sched2 = BackgroundScheduler()

       sched1.add_job(job1, 'interval', hours=1)
       sched2.add_job(job2, 'interval', hours=4)

       sched1.start()
       sched2.start()
```

I did not try above code because I cannot figure the first part that is to make it work starting on Monday8 am to Friday 5pm

Answer (score 0):

First off, why do you have more than one scheduler? Next, there is nothing stopping your application from exiting at the end here, so maybe use `BlockingScheduler` instead.

As for the actual question, maybe `CronTrigger` is what you want? You can specify the start and end weekdays, so for `job1` which uses a 1 hour interval, you could do:

```
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

trigger1 = CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon', hour='8-')
trigger2 = CronTrigger(day_of_week='tue-thu', hour='*')
trigger3 = CronTrigger(day_of_week='fri', hour='-17')
sched.add_job(job1, 'or', trigger1, trigger2, trigger3)
```

For `job2`, you could use `hour='*/4'` on `trigger2` to make it run every 4th hour on the clock.